# What's the C# equivalent to C++'s dynamic_cast?

Tags: c#, c++, casting

This C++ code checks if `o` is a `Node *` and if so, calls a method on `d`.

```
if (Node * d = dynamic_cast<Node *>(o)) d->do_it();
```

What's the shortest and/or most efficient way to write the equivalent in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of C# 6 (July 2015), assuming `Node` is a `class` (or [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/), `string`, etc), using your example where you

1. check if `o` is a `Node` (not actually the same as converting `o` *to* a `Node`--see note about casting vs converting below)
2. if so, call `do_it()`
3. immediately discard the cast value

you can use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```cs
(o as Node)?.do_it();
```

This syntax also handles the case where `o` is, in fact, declared as `Node`, but happens to be `null`.

If you want to keep the cast variable, as of C# 7 (March 2017), you can run:

```cs
if (o is Node node)
{
    node.do_it();
}
```

The variable `node` at this point is in the scope outside of the `if` statement, equivalent to:

```cs
Node node = o as Node;
if (node != null) 
{
    node.do_it();
}
```

So, if you want to only continue the execution *if* `o` is a `Node`, you can write:

```
if (!(o is Node node)) 
{
    return; // or continue, etc
}

node.do_it();
// ...
```

Note: The `is` keyword will *always* return `false` if `o` is `null`, even if you directly specify the type and then ask if that variable is that type.

```cs
string foo = null;
if (foo is string)
{
    // never gets here
    Console.WriteLine(foo);
}
```

#### Casting vs Converting

The `is` and `as` keywords do the same as C++'s `dynamic_cast<T>`: they will check against the specified type, subtype, or interface, but will not actually change the value in memory.  They simply tell the compiler which methods should be available on the variable.

There's a misnomer amongst C# users where we use the words "cast" and "convert" interchangeably.  This likely stems from the fact that we often *know* that a base type variable is always going to be a subtype, and so we use the *convert* syntax when puritanically we should be using the cast syntax:

```cs
void Foo(MyBaseType value)
{
    // let's assume `value` will always be a MySubType
    MySubType subTypeValue = (MySubType)value;
}
```

This syntax will throw at runtime if `value` is not, in fact, `MySubType`.

Converting differs from casting in that the value in memory *may* change.  Consider `int` and `double`.

```cs
void Foo()
{
    // implicit converting
    int x = 1;
    double y = x;

    // explicit converting
    y = 1.5;
    x = (int)y;
}
```

In each of these cases, the literal value stored in memory changes format.  `int`s can always be represented by a `double`--there will never be a loss in data--and so there is a defined `implicit operator` that will manipulate the data in memory into the new format.  `double`s, being floating point values and having a range larger than `int`s, cannot guarantee no loss in data, so C# requires an explicit conversion (usually termed "explicit cast") via the `explicit operator` to indicate to the compiler that we're okay with losing data.

With classes, we can define our own implicit and explicit operators which will manipulate the data whatever way we see fit.  This is where the misnomer between *convert* and *cast* gets messy.

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Bar bar = (Bar)foo;

        // writes "1" (or would, if the program compiled)
        Console.WriteLine(bar);

        // throws compilation error: "Cannot convert type `Foo' to `Bar' via built-in conversion"
        bar = foo as Bar;

        // note: the same would happen if `foo` was type int? and `bar` was type `double?`
        //       even though double? can be converted to int?
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public readonly int Value = 1;

    public static explicit operator Bar(Foo foo)
    {
        return new Bar(foo.Value.ToString());
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public readonly string Value;

    public Bar(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Assuming that `Node` is a `class` then do the following

```
Node d = o as Node;
if (d != null) {
  d.do_it();
}
```

If instead it's a `struct` then try this

```
if (o is Node) {
  ((Node)o).do_it();
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, +1 on the difference between struct and class (in terms of validity of `as`)

Comment: why wouldn't you use the "is" operator on reference types??  `if (o is Node) { (o as Node).do_it(); }`

Comment: @JohnRuiz there's no reason you couldn't.  In fact the second method will work regardless of whether Node is a struct or a class

Comment: @JohnRuiz using the `is` + `as` combo causes the runtime type check to be performed twice.  A runtime type check is generally speaking more expensive than a simple `null` check so the more optimal way to write the code is a `as` + `null` check.  Both are correct though.

Answer (score 1):

The `as` operator returns null if `o` is not a `Node`:

```
Node d = o as Node;
if (d != null)
{
    d.do_it();
}
```

Comment: Unless Node is a `struct`, then it won't compile.

Comment: But judging by the code he posted, he uses pointers, as in reference types, as in classes. Besides, a struct in C# should very seldom be used.

Comment: True in theory, but in C++ `struct` and `class` can have pointers.  A `struct` could conceivably be used for a node.

Comment: He is asking about C# lets stop talking about C++ he asked a specfic question about C# syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is` keyword in C#.

```
if (o is Node) 
{

}
```

Comment: Actually `is` doesn't cast.  `is` just checks type.