# C# dynamic casts when using Entity Framework for insertion

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database which contains tables of mapping values for a variety of objects.

For example the `Colour` table contains `BLK > Black, BLU > BLUE, ORA > ORANGE` etc.. and the `CarType` table contains `4DH > Four-door hatchback, 4WD > Four wheel drive` etc...

I'm using Entity Framework code-first so I have a context set up something like this.

```
public class MappingContext : DbContext
{
    public MappingContext ()
        : base("Mappings")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Colour> ColourMappings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CarType> CarTypeMappings { get; set; }
}
```

Every object that relates to each table in my `Mapping` database inherits from a base class like so:

```
public class Mapping
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string OrignalValue { get; set; }

    public string MappedValue { get; set; }
}

public class CarType : Mapping{}
public class Colour : Mapping{}
```

Now what I want to do is read these mappings in from an XML file filled with "Templates" which contain the mappings and insert them in the DB.

I have the following method to do this:

```
public void InsertMappings(XDocument xml, string templateName, Type typeToInsert)
{
    // Here I find the relevent mappings 

    using (var repo = new Repository())
    {
        var mapppings = mappings.Select(mapping => new Mapping
        {
            MappedValue = mapping.Value,
            OrignalValue = GetCode(mapping)
        });

        foreach (var mapping in mapppings.ToList())
        {
            var map = (typeToInsert)mapping  // << This line will not compile

            repo.Insert(map);
        }

    repo.Save();
   }
}
```

This will not complie as it doesnt recognise the attempted cast "(typeToInsert)mapping".

So basically what I need to know is how to I cast this Mapping object to a Specific Mapping object when it comes to inserting it into the db? Or any suggestions for a better way of doing this!

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925718/c-dynamic-runtime-cast

Comment: I'm assuming you are dynamically resolving `typeToInsert` at some point, and passing the type identifier to `InsertMappings` - i.e. you can't just use a generic `InsertMappings<T>` method? (stupid question really... just checking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it you are trying to cast an instance of `Mapping` as a `CarType` or `Colour` which won't work because `Mapping` doesn't know anything about those types as it's the **base** class.

Your code would need to create an instance of the concrete type i.e. `typeToInsert` and cast it as `Mapping`. You could do something like:

```
public void InsertMappings(XDocument xml, string templateName, Type typeToInsert)
{
    // Here I find the relevent mappings 

    using (var repo = new Repository())
    {
        foreach (var m in mappings)
        {
            // XML -> Entity
            var mapping = (typeToInsert)Activator.CreateInstance(typeToInsert);
            (mapping as Mapping).MappedValue = m.Value;
            (mapping as Mapping).OriginalValue = GetCode(m);
            // Update database
            repo.Insert(mapping);
        }
        repo.Save();
   }
}
```

You should probably be making use of generics here as well, you could refactor your method to look like:

```
public void InsertMappings<T>(XDocument xml, string templateName)
{
    // Here I find the relevent mappings 

    using (var repo = new Repository())
    {
        foreach (var m in mappings)
        {
            // XML -> Entity
            var mapping = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            (mapping as Mapping).MappedValue = m.Value;
            (mapping as Mapping).OriginalValue = GetCode(m);
            // Update database
            repo.Insert(mapping);
        }
        repo.Save();
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
InsertMappings<CarType>(xmlDoc, "CarTemplate");
InsertMappings<Colour>(xmlDoc, "ColourTemplate");
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but the line "repo.Insert((T)mapping);" still gives me a compilation error - Cannot cast expression of Type 'Mapping' to type 'T'?