# Creating instance of a generic type from a instance of the type parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I have a BL consisting of a generic Repository and some specific implementations for a couple of entity types (My DAL is a Entity Framework 5 model). The Repository uses for almost all it's functionality the method Set() of the System.Data.Entity.DbContext. I have some Expressions for things like getting siblings of a entity T, these won't work on the result of Set(Type entityType).

At one moment I have a instance of a non-generic DbEntityEntry. The entity is of type Object. When I use GetType() I get the approptiate Entity Type. I know want to get the related entity using my functions in Repository. Is there a way to do this from the non-generic DbEntityEntry.

I tried:

```
public Repository(T entity)
{
    \\ Construction here
}
```

But I get a `Repository<Object>` and the call to `Set<Object>` returns nothing as expected.

I've searched for a way to do this but came up empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this example posted by George Mauer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925718/c-dynamic-runtime-cast) thread. It requires .Net 4.0 or higher.

```
dynamic DynamicCast(object entity, Type to)
{
    var openCast = this.GetType().GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var closeCast = openCast.MakeGenericMethod(to);
    return closeCast.Invoke(entity, new[] { entity });
}
static T Cast<T>(object entity) where T : object
{
    return entity as T;
}
```

You can use a slightly modified variant of this to create a matching `Repository` instance:

```
public static dynamic CreateRepository(object entiry, Type targetType)
{
    Type BaseType = typeof(Repository<>);   
    Type ConcreteType = BaseType.MakeGenericType(targetType);
    var Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(ConcreteType, entiry);

    return DynamicCast(Instance, ConcreteType);
}
```

Comment: Added a example implementation of ´CreateRepository´

Comment: I can't really see a meaning of the `DynamicCast` method. Why not change the last code line of the `CreateRepository` method above to simply `return Instance;`?

Comment: Because Activator.CreateInstance has a return type `Object`. By using DynamicCast you get the correct type.

Comment: I propose the following simplification: `public static object CreateRepository(object entity) { var typeDef = typeof(Repository<>); var constrType = typeDef.MakeGenericType(entity.GetType()); var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constrType, entity); return instance; }`

Comment: (to your latest comment): But you can just use the implicit conversion from any type to type `dynamic` if you want, as in `dynamic retVal = new object();`?

Comment: By using dymanic the CLR evaluates the type at runtime. By using your suggesting you would simply get a instance of type `Object` since that´s what Activator.CreateInstance returns. In constrast, by using the DynamicCast Method the CLR knows the concrete type - you loose that info by directly returning the `Activator.CreateInstance` result.

Comment: You seem to confuse _compile-time type_ with _runtime type_, at least that's what I think. You can take my exact simplification in the comment above, and change the return type to `dynamic` (that is `public static dynamic CreateRepository(object entity) ...`), if you like `dynamic`. A cast (reference conversion) does ***not*** change the runtime type. It's a compile-time thing.

Comment: I´m aware of the difference between _compile-time_ and _runtime_ type but i wasn´t aware of how `dynamic` evaluates a statement. You´re right, simply skipping `DyamicCast` should yield the same result. And no, actualy i dislike dynamic but it´s the only solution i could think of in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of a generic type is part of the *specific* class generated for its generic type argument. For instance, the constructor of a `List<int>` is a *different* constructor than that of a `List<string>`. In other words, the code that "finds" the type cannot exist inside the generic class.

As far as I know these are your two options:

- convert the object to its actual type (a factory-like solution)
- use reflection to create the generic class instance

To create an instance using reflection, you can use:

```
Type genericType = typeof(List<>);
Type genericArgument = typeof(int);
Type specificType = genericType.MakeGenericType(genericArgument);
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(specificType); // this is a List<int>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can constraint your generic types to have a parameterless constructor, this problem can be solved pretty elegantly

```
public Repository(T entity) where T : new()
{
    T foo = new T(); //that's it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
T entity = default(T);
```

This works for both value types of T, as well as structs and classes. Where T is a class however it does require a parameterless constructor.