# Managing Multiple settings in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, settings

I have created two settings file under properties in c#. Basically I have to apply settings based on a particular set of condition

for example the settings file are "myset1" and "myset2"

both these settings have similar structure

```
myset1
  price = 100
  qty = 100

myset2
  price = 150
  qty = 20
```

in my application, if value of variable "appColor" is "blue" myset1 has to be used if variable "appColor" is "red" myset2 has to be used.

in my code

```
productPrice.Text = //based on the "appColor" selection value from myset1 or myset2 has to be displayed.
```

I tried this but not working

```
Settings setSelector = new Settings();

if(appColor == "blue")
{
    setSelector = myset1.Default;
}
else(appColor == "red")
{
    setSelector = myset2.Default;
}
```

I am getting error that "cannot convert source type "myset1" to settings"

**EDIT:** my aim is that productPrice.Text = setSelector.Price; remains same even when settings are changed so I don't have to change code here and just have to change the settings. basically full forms gets filled based on the settings selected.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: why add the `.Default`?

Comment: where are you instantiating the `myset1` and `myset2` vars?

Comment: instantiating is done on app loading. value is checked when the value of appColor changes, i.e. when combobox selection changes.

Comment: Your error is simply telling you that your `myset1.Default` variable is not of type `Settings`.

Comment: Are myset1 and myset2 actual settings files?

Comment: I understand the error, but I don't know how to apply particular setting based on selection, thats my question

Comment: yeah @MarkHall they are actually setting files under project proerties

Comment: That would normally just be one settings file, do you actually have two or are you using two different settings in the same file if so what is their datatype

Comment: @MarkHall I have created two settings file and the datatype of price and qty are int, do let me know if there is another way of achieving what I want, thanks.

Comment: one last question, does this have to be available to multiple methods or only in the method that you are setting it.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with it a bit and referencing this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) specifically the last section on adding alternate sets of settings.

> To Add an Additional Set of Settings
>
> 1. From the Project menu, choose Add New Item. The Add New Item dialog box opens.
> 2. In the Add New Item dialog box, select Settings File.
> 3. In the Name box, give the settings file a name, such as SpecialSettings.settings, and click Add to add the file to your
>      solution.
> 4. In Solution Explorer, drag the new settings file into the Properties folder. This allows your new settings to be available in
>      code.
> 5. Add and use settings in this file as you would any other settings file. You can access this group of settings through the
>      Properties.SpecialSettings object.

I then realized that each settings file is its own separate class therefore you have to go back to a common class. By doing so you will loose your individual properties and have to cast it to the proper class. I then looked at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925718/c-dynamic-runtime-cast) searching for dynamic casting. According to JaredPar's answer it appears that the easiest way to do this would be to use the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) keyword and let the class type be figured out at runtime.

i.e.

Class level Declaration:

```
dynamic setSelector;
```

Intializing it during Form Load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(appColor == "blue")
    {
        setSelector = Properties.myset1.Default;
    }
    else if(appColor == "red")
    {
       setSelector = Properties.myset2.Default;
    }

    textBox1.Text = setSelector.qty.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried below code. it worked correctly.

[image: Settings]
[image: Settings1]

I have two Textboxes, in which i am setting Price and Qty based on color.

```html
            Object obj = new Object();

            if(appColor == "blue")
            {
                obj = (System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyCollection)Properties.Settings.Default.Properties;
                
            }
            else(appColor == "red")
            {
                obj = (System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyCollection)Properties.Settings1.Default.Properties;
            }
            foreach (System.Configuration.SettingsProperty p in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
            {
                if (p.Name=="Qty")
                    textBox1.Text = p.DefaultValue.ToString();
                else if (p.Name=="Price")
                    textBox2.Text = p.DefaultValue.ToString();
            }
```

I Hope this helps :)