# How to convert object to type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, types, generic-programming

I have a generic method that returns an object. At certain scenarios I would like this object to be a list and therefor I wish to access a list property on the object. In order to be able to do that i need to convert the object to an object type.

I have an object that has data

```
object obj
```

I am trying:

```
Type t = obj.GetType();

var t1 = (t)obj;
```

In order to access a list property on the object:

```
 Type t = obj.GetType();

  var t1 = (t)obj;

  return t1.items.Tolist();
```

How do I do this?

EDIT:

if i would already know the type like for example:

```
Type t = obj.GetType();

var t1 = (ApiResult<IEnumerable<AlarmLog>>)obj;

return t1.Items.ToList();
```

This would work, but the type is unknown and Im looking to find the type, convert it and then return my desiered list.

Comment: Yes, since there are scenarios I need this to be an object.

Comment: you can't do that `Type` is a runtime concept. casting is a compile time concept.

Comment: consider using generics or `dynamic`.

Comment: It's *always* an object.

Comment: Yes it is, sorry,  What i mean is that i wish the object to contain only list items in a scertain scenario

Comment: If you're looking for a specific type, why can't you check to see if `t` is of that type then cast?

Comment: you can use `as` : `var obj2 = obj as X; if(obj2 != null) { obj2.items... }`

Comment: @kalamazoowho I am trying to avoid typing in a hardcoded type. I am asking if there is a way that I can get the type, cast it to that type and then get my items from the list

Comment: Please check edits

Comment: How do you know that `obj` will always have `.Items`?

Comment: @Matteo Umili it is not shown but i have a bolean property that i set to true when I want a list and then I know that the obj has items.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN you should always hardcode the type, not doing so will lead to confusion. If you know the object is a Collection when a bool is set, cast it to that.

Comment: "I am trying to avoid typing in a hardcoded type" -- Pretty sure the signature [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4925885/5095502) is your only option, then. You get no compiler help with `dynamic` so you have to manually make sure you don't make any typos and ensure properties actually exist on an object and etc..

Comment: @Night5h4d3 the thing is that It is not only one type. I would have to build logic for several types. I was hoping to find a cleaner soloution. sending in a dynamic property to the method is an alternative that i have considered but I was curious if this was possible.

Comment: Is the property always called `items`? The best solution would be to create an interface containing the relevant properties and have your classes implement it. Otherwise you need to use reflection/dynamic to access the `items` property dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I descided to change this up since interface alternatives would involve more work for me which I was not happy about.
@Quantic provided me with a link to a good soloution. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't find time to do things right, when will you find time to do things over? The interface option is a bit of extra work now, but puts you in a better position for the life of the product.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a problem with your implementation of your generic method. If you're working with purely custom objects, an interface would solve all of your problems:

```
public interface IMask {}

public class MyObject : IMask {}

public class Driver
{
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
        Driver d = new Driver();
        MyObject mo = d.SomeMethod(/*some param*/);
    }

    public IMask<T> SomeMethod(/*some param*/) where T : IMask
    {
        //some code
        return new IMask();
    }
}
```

The above snippet works for custom classes. By returning IMask, you can safely cast it to a type that inherits from that interface. The method actually doing the work is completely generic in that it only accepts objects of type IMask and returns a generic object of type IMask.

If you're working with .Net classes, it becomes a matter of what kind of object you're returning and what you want to cast it to. You mentioned a List, but what is the other return type? Converting between string and List can become a bit of a problem and it might be better to

A) Wrap that in a custom object
or
B) Add this logic to your working method.

We probably need more information to answer this in a more specific manner.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would be a bit overkill for me but a good attempt.

Answer (score 2):

```
static bool TryCastAsList<T>(object input, out IList<T> output)
{
    IEnumerable inputAsIEnumerable = input as IEnumerable;
    if (inputAsIEnumerable != null)
    {
        output = inputAsIEnumerable.Cast<T>().ToList();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        output = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
object o1 = new []{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IList<int> l1;
if (TryCastAsList(o1, out l1))
{
    int n = l1.First(); // 1
}

object o2 = new[] { "Hello", "World" };
IList<string> l2;
if (TryCastAsList(o2, out l2))
{
    string s = l2.First();  // Hello
}
```

If the passed object is Enumerable, then `TryCastAsList` casts all elements as the generic type T and returns true, else it returns false.