# How to convert dynamic or object to strongly typed objects in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Class in which below properties are there.

```
Public class Classifields
{
 public int ID {get;set;}
 public Name {get; set;}
 public Type {get; set;}
}
```

The above object is used as child object in an parent.
So the Parent Object will contain the Id of this Classifields.

For some purpose I am taking all the properties of the parent class with the related objects loaded into it, Which means Parent and child object also loaded.

I am taking the properties in this way like below.

```
 PropertyInfo[] allProps = typeof(T).GetProperties();            
 return allProps;
```

So the returned properties will have some time the single Classifields or some times multiple classifields.

I take value like below

```
var newValue = prop.GetValue(model, null);
```

For the Classifields list property , I am checking for property fullname contains "Classifields" or not and passing the list of classifields or single Classfields as dynamic object to process and take the Name with comma separated value from the list or single item.

When it is multiple entry I try to use IList of object to typecast the dynamic it works correctly but when it comes as single object it fails because it is not IList.

At the same time I tried with foreach Classifields but that also not works.

```
if(val.FullName.Contains("Classifields"))
  {
   old = (oldV != null) ? GetNames(oldV) : null;
   new = (newV != null) ? GetNames(newV) : null;
  }

public string GetNames(dynamic stringDatatoProcess)
    {
        if (stringDatatoProcess== null)
            return "";
        try
        {
            string Names = "";
            if (stringDatatoProcess!= null)
            {
                dynamic dynamicDog = stringDatatoProcess;
                string values = string.Empty;
               //IList<Classifields> classfields = dynamicDog;
                StringBuilder stringvalues = new StringBuilder();
                foreach(Classification classification in dynamicDog)
                {
                    stringvalues.Append(classification.ClsName);
                    stringvalues.Append(",");
                }
                ClsNames = stringvalues.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
            }
            return ClsNames;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

How to handle this situation because I cant check the count as well since it is dynamic object. And I am not able to count the items because it is throwing the exception while typecasting itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#: Dynamic runtime cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925718/c-dynamic-runtime-cast)

Comment: if ``dynamicDog`` is a collection, try this :``if (dynamicDog is IList list1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list1.Count);
            }``