# Cast object variable with Type variable

Tags: c#

I have a variable with `object` type that contain, how example `string` value, and `Type` variable that contain `string` type. I gave a `string` as an example, but in general a type variable can contain any type that is the type of a variable.

```
var result = MethodThatDoingSomething(); //return the tuple (Type, object)

//Variables just for better understanding

Type typeResult = result.Item1;
object valueResult = result.Item2;

var typedValue = valueResult as typeResult; //here i got an error
//Cannot resolve symbol 'typeResult'
```

I tried and next realization and got same error

```
var typedValue = (typeResult)valueResult;
//Cannot resolve symbol 'typeResult'
```

And I don't quite understand how to solve this problem...

Comment: Why not use `GetType()`? If you want to do this then use [typeof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator)

Comment: I tried GetType() too, and got same error

Comment: Casting is purely a compile-time function (telling the compiler to interact with the object as an object of the casted type. There's no point in casting if you don't know the type at compile-time.

Comment: `var typedValue` if you don't know the type if the variable until runtime, what is the point of casting it? What do you hope to achieve by casting it? Perhaps you can cast it to an interface or something?

Comment: To be more constructive, what do you plan to _do_ with the typed object after you cast? There may be a better way to do _that_.

Comment: Else you have to start looking into `dynamic` if this is really what you want

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972636/casting-a-variable-using-a-type-variable

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925718/c-dynamic-runtime-cast

Comment: It's true that `dynamic` lets you do some weird stuff, but I strongly recommend not going down that path. 99.99% of the time it's just an issue with figuring out the language and understanding how to write the code so that we don't need to do stuff like this at runtime. We can almost always write code so that we know what the type is and don't have to do anything odd. It's just a matter of getting over the hump to where it makes sense and we know how to do that.