# Hangfire Backgroundjob Enqueue via deserilaziation object problem

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, hangfire, abp

Normally i can enqueue hangfire jobs without problem.
I'am trying to enqueue jobs dynamically getting object/argument from database.
I am generating parameters via deserilization, invoicationdata is being generated incorrect (as object).
(I am using ABP framework but i do not think this problem is related with ABP.)

job Enqueue:

```
public class JobExecuter
{
    private readonly IBackgroundJobInboxRepository backgroundJobInboxRepository;
    private readonly IJsonSerializer jsonSerializer;
    private readonly IBackgroundJobManager backgroundJobManager;
    public JobExecuter(
        IBackgroundJobInboxRepository backgroundJobInboxRepository,
        IJsonSerializer jsonSerializer,
        IBackgroundJobManager backgroundJobManager)
    {
        this.backgroundJobInboxRepository = backgroundJobInboxRepository;
        this.jsonSerializer = jsonSerializer;
        this.backgroundJobManager = backgroundJobManager;
    }
    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
        {
            var item = await backgroundJobInboxRepository.FirstOrDefault();
            var type = Type.GetType(item.AssemblyName);
            var obj = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(type, item.Arguments, false);
            await backgroundJobManager.EnqueueAsync(obj);
        }
}
```

item.AssemblyName :

> MyAssembly.BackgroundJobs.MyClass, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

concrete class:

```
public class HangfireBackgroundJobManager : IBackgroundJobManager, ITransientDependency
{
    public virtual Task<string> EnqueueAsync<TArgs>(TArgs args, BackgroundJobPriority priority = BackgroundJobPriority.Normal,
        TimeSpan? delay = null)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(BackgroundJob.Enqueue<HangfireJobExecutionAdapter<TArgs>>(adapter => adapter.ExecuteAsync(args)));
    }
}
```

my invocationdata:

> {"Type":"Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.Hangfire.HangfireJobExecutionAdapter`1[[**System.Object,
> System.Private.CoreLib**, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.HangFire,
> Version=5.3.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null","Method":"ExecuteAsync","ParameterTypes":"["**System.Object,
> System.Private.CoreLib**, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"]","Arguments":"["{\"CurrentDate\":\"2022-09-15T00:00:00+03:00\",\"DateInterval\":-5,\"ProjectId\":11}"]"}

invocationdata that should be:

> {"Type":"Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.Hangfire.HangfireJobExecutionAdapter`1[[**MyAssembly.BackgroundJobs.MyClass,
> MyAssembly**, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
> Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.HangFire, Version=5.3.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null","Method":"ExecuteAsync","ParameterTypes":"["**MyAssembly.BackgroundJobs.MyClass,
> MyAssembly**, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null"]","Arguments":"["{\"CurrentDate\":\"2022-09-15T00:00:00+03:00\",\"DateInterval\":-5,\"ProjectId\":11}"]"}

Additional info: You can access real [HangfireBackgroundJobManager](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/9330abedaf564b4712f58d9b285749ac70277d86/framework/src/Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.HangFire/Volo/Abp/BackgroundJobs/Hangfire/HangfireBackgroundJobManager.cs) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using these [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4925924/4458106)

```
dynamic DynamicCast(object entity, Type to)
{
   var openCast = this.GetType().GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
   var closeCast = openCast.MakeGenericMethod(to);
   return closeCast.Invoke(this, new[] { entity });
}
static T Cast<T>(object entity) where T : class
{
   return entity as T;
}
public async Task ExecuteAsync()
{
   var item = await backgroundJobInboxRepository.FirstOrDefault();
   var type = Type.GetType(item.AssemblyName);
   var obj2 = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(type, item.Arguments, false);
   var obj = DynamicCast(obj2, type); // ADDED
   await backgroundJobManager.EnqueueAsync(obj);
}
```