# Cast to any type

Tags: c#, .net, types, casting

I have a txt file where from I can extract two strings (type and value). But, I need to cast it to the correct type. See the code bellow.

```
string type;
string value;

//example 1 //from the txt file
type = "int";
value = "25";

//example 2
type = "double";
value = "1.3";

//example 3
type = "string";
value = "blablabla";

//conversion I would like to do:
dynamic finalResult = (type)element.Value; //this returns an error
```

I need to do something like this, but I don't know to create a object type from the content of the string.

I tried to declare a Type:

```
Type myType = type;
```

But I dont know how to do it correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#: Dynamic runtime cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925718/c-dynamic-runtime-cast)

Comment: plus you need to call Type.GetType, to get a type from its name

Comment: Your question is very confusing. `"int"` is a string. `typeof(int)` is a type. You don't need dynamic at all here.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly?why would you do this?

Comment: The txt file has a large ammount of lines. Each line has these two information (type and value). Sometimes the value is 1, but the type is double. And other times, the value is 3, but the type is string. I need to send these with the correct type to a method. And the correct type is written in the txt file.

Comment: `dynamic` not meant for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the name of clarity and type safety I think you should just use a combination of a switch expression and the various `.TryParse()` methods, having it return a generic type

```cs
static T? ReadVariable<T>(string type, string value) =>
    type switch  
    {  
        "int" => int.TryParse(value, out int val) ? val : null, //null or throw an ex
        "double" => double.TryParse(value, out double val) ? val : null,
        "string" => string.TryParse(value, out string val) ? val : null,
        "bool" => bool.TryParse(value, out bool val) ? val : null,
        //... etc
        _ => throw new NotSupportedException("This type is currently not supported")
    };

int? num = ReadVariable<int>("int", "99"); //nullable return

//nullable handling
int num = ReadVariable<int>("int", "99") ?? default(int); //int type's default value is 0
int num = ReadVariable<int>("int", "99").GetValueOrDefault(-1); //default to an int value of your choice
```

Are you *really* going to have a situation where you need to parse out *any* type under the sun? This method allows you to maintain full control over what happens. Use of `dynamic` may potentially be way more headache than you expect

Update: thanks to @ckuri for pointing out that you may also want to use the [try parse overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0#system-int32-tryparse(system-readonlyspan((system-char))-system-globalization-numberstyles-system-iformatprovider-system-int32@)) that allows for invariant culture in order to account for international numbering schemes

Update 2: added an examples of nullable handling

Comment: The TryParse methods should use the overload that takes a CultureInfo and fill it with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Otherwise, it will break if run  on machines which don’t use the period as the decimal separator.

Comment: @ckuri this is a very good point, thank you, will link that documentation

Answer (score 2):

does this work?

```
object result;
string value = "some value";
string type = "some type";
switch(type)
{
   case "int":
      result = Convert.ToInt32(value);
      break;
   case "double":
      result = Convert.ToDouble(value);
      break;
   case "string":
      result = value;
      break;
   // case "any other datatype":
   //    result = convert explicitly to that datatype
}
```

Comment: `dynamic` is not needed

Comment: @T.S. how then should this be done?

Comment: `dynamic` is for late binding operations, unknown structures, etc. here - use `object`.