# where exactly implicit conversion method be put

Tags: c#, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, user-defined-types

```
public class Faranheit 
{
    public float Digree { get; set; }

    public Faranheit(float f) 
    {
        Digree = f;
    }

    public static implicit operator Celcius(Faranheit f)
    {
        return new Celcius((5.0f / 9.0f) * (f.Digree - 32));
    }

    public static implicit operator Faranheit(Celcius c)
    {
        return new Faranheit((9.0f / 5.0f) * c.Digree + 32);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Celcius
{
    public float Digree{get;set;}

    public Celcius(float c)
    {
        Digree = c;
    }

}
```

I am just confused, where to put the conversion methods exactly..

It works fine even if I put one method in one class and other in the other, or I interchange them or even if I put both  of them in any of the two classes..

But if I put it outside these two classes it doesn't work (compile error)..

Could please someone put some light on this..

**EDIT:**

if it allows the conversion methods to be in either of the class, why doesn't it allow the conversion method to be in a separate class??

Comment: What compilation error are you getting?

Comment: Minor quibble: it's "Fahrenheit". And "Degree".

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672742/cast-class-into-another-class-or-convert-class-to-another

Comment: @AdamV: that's not what I am talking about..I don't think that's the reason for my problem.. ;)

Comment: @dotNETbeginner: that's why I wrote this as a comment and not as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

All that matters is that the implicit conversion exists in one of the two classes. I would tend to put both conversions in the less-commonly used class.

In this case, the classes look equal, so I would put the conversion *to* the class in each class i.e. the conversion from F to C would go in the Celsius class, and vice versa.

Really, it's mostly about personal preference.

In this specific case, I would write a Temperature class that lets you get the temperature in C, F, K, R, etc. But that isn't exactly relevant to the actual question.

Comment: My question actually is, if it allows the conversion methods to be in either of the class, why doesn't it allow the conversion method to be in a separate class??

Answer (score -1):

I would put them in each of the classes. So you can do stuff like:

```
Celsius c = new Celsius(Value);
Fahrenheit f = c.toFahrenheit();
Celsius newC = f.toCelsius();
```

edit: or if you wanted to go the Helper class route, you could do:

```
public static class ConvertTemps
{
    public static Celsius toCelsius(Fahrenheit F)
    {
        return new Celsius(5/8* F - 32);
    }
    public static Fahrenheit toFahrenheit(Celsius C)
    {
        return new Fahrenheit(8/5*C + 32);
    }
}
```

and then you could do things like:

```
Celsius c = new Celsius(value);
Fahrenheit f = ConvertTemps.toFahrenheit(c);
```

But I'd go the first route.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that. Good point. Guess that's a pretty important one. Well, given that, you definitely want one in each class.