# Cast Action<T1> to Action<T2> in c# where T1 and T2 have no relation

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, delegates

I've got two objects which (Domain and Data) which in this case have the same property (let's presume Name). I've got an `Action<DomItem>` which I would like to cast to `Action<DataItem>`.

```
public  class DomItem {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DataItem {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Program {
    public Program() {
        Action<DomItem> domAction = new Action<DomItem>(x=>x.Name = "Test");
        // Something Casted To Action<DataItem>(x=>x.Name = "Test");
    }
}
```

Of course this is just a basic example. It's by design that I can NOT use a common interface. I do not care about the `DataItem` might not be having the same property.

I've been looking into Expressions and several other solutions but I just can't figure out how to create the Cast (or get the "x=>x.Name =..." part from the method).

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Why don't just use AutoMapper?

Comment: Please explain how oleksii.

Comment: Christian, It's just an example. I want the DataItem to run the action on itself which I've defined on the DomItem.

Comment: In response to Oleksii: I have the Actions defined based on my DomItem. I need to translate them to Actions based on DataItem. It's not that I want to use Before or After Mapping. I really need to cast the Actions.

Comment: @MightyMouseTheSecond OK I see. You will probably need to use reflection to get the delegates parts and then translate them into your DataItem context.

Comment: @Christian I've been looking into that but I can't seem to get the cast to work. I'm pretty lost for any solution ;-)

Comment: so you want some kind of duck-typing-variance-cast ... don't do this (it might actually work if you just go `dynamic`) - you basically say good-bye to the type-checker - in the case at hand just implement it by hand - it will even be faster at runtime (yeah it's copy&past - so what?)

Comment: @Carsten you are correct by stating that copy&past is possible. That would be my last resort. But I still would like to know if it's even possible to cast the Action (I've been searching and trying for quite some time now).

Comment: By any chance are you actually have `Expression<Action<T>>` instead of `Action<T>`, it makes the problem a lot easier.

Comment: @MightyMouseTheSecond Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3673216/360674) answer. Should be something what you need.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Could you explain how to create an Expression<Action<T>>. At this point I get confused how to create an Expression<Action<T>>.

Comment: `x=>x.Name = "Test"` is a valid `Expression<Action<T>>` too so you could just do `Expression<Action<DomItem>> domAction = x=>x.Name = "Test";`. Expressions are what you normally work with when dealing with EntityFramework or similar.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It gives me an exception: An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly or indirectly cast a `Action<DomItem>` to an `Action<DataItem>`, but you could *wrap* the action with a converter that converts the input from a `DataItem` to a `DomItem` and runs the original action on the copy:

```
public Action<DataItem> Convert(Action<DomItem> action)
{
    return new Action<DataItem>(o => action(Map(o)));
}

public DomItem Map(DataItem dataItem)
{
    return new DomItem{Name = dataItem.Name};
}
```

The obvious downside is that the action will be applied to a *copy* of the original object and not the original object itself.  Without knowing exactly what the action is I don't know of a way to "cast" the action without a common base type.

Comment: this won't work as the action is not to set the name but I want the DataItem (which goes to EF) to perform a certain SQLQuery (hence the Action). I tried to simplify the question to prevent a huge amount of code. I really need to know how to cast an Action<T1> to an Action<T2> and not a work-arround. Thank you for your anwser.

Comment: You can't cast an `Action<T1>` to an `Action<T2>`.  Note that the action returned is not setting the name - it's wrapping the _original_ action  passing in a new `DomItem` with the properties mapped from the original `DataItem`.

Comment: Thank you for the input @D-stanley. I will try to find another sollution.