# EF Core cannot convert from query select of anonymous type to DTO object class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am having trouble casting the results of a custom query to a list of DTO objects. I am using EF Core 5.0.0.

Here is my DTO class:

```
public class UserPoolDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string StyleName { get; set; }
    public decimal RegCost { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegStartTimeUTC { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegEndTimeUTC { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

This `UserPoolDto` is used in a view model as a simple list like so:

```
public class UserPoolVm
{
    public IList<UserPoolDto> Pools { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code that uses EF core to query the DB and try to cast the results to a list of `UserPoolDto` objects to be assigned to my view model:

```
    public async Task<UserPoolVm> Handle(GetUserPoolsQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var pools = await _context.Pools
                                  .Include(p => p.Type)
                                  .Include(p => p.Type.Category)
                                  .Include(p => p.Style)
                                  .Select(p => new
                                               {
                                                    p.Id,
                                                    p.Name,
                                                    p.Key,
                                                    TypeName = p.Type.Name,
                                                    CategoryName = p.Type.Category.Name,
                                                    StyleName = p.Style.Name,
                                                    p.RegCost,
                                                    p.RegStartTimeUTC,
                                                    p.RegEndTimeUTC,
                                                    p.Icon,
                                                    p.Description,
                                                    p.Instructions,
                                                    p.CreatedBy,
                                                })
                                  .Where(x => x.CreatedBy == request.UserId)
                                  .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        return new UserPoolVm
                   {
                       Pools = pools // ERROR IS THROWN ON THIS LINE
                   };
}
```

However, the project won't build and I get the following error (I broke the property types into separate lines so they are easier to compare with the class properties above):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type:  long Id, string Name, string Key, string TypeName, string CategoryName, string StyleName, decimal RegCost, System.DateTime  RegStartTimeUTC, System.DateTime RegEndTimeUTC, string Icon, string Description, string Instructions, string CreatedBy
> to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Application.Pools.Queries.GetUserPools.UserPoolDto>'.
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I've tried adding an explicit cast like so:

```
        return new UserPoolVm
        {
            Pools = (IList<UserPoolDto>)pools
        };
```

This lets the project build and run but I get the exact same error above as a runtime error instead of an error that prevents building.

I have checked multiple times to make sure the number, type, and name of all fields returns matches the `UserPoolDto`. It all matches. I can even debug the code and confirm that the objects returned by the query match the DTO object.  However it still won't cast the results.

**Question**: can someone help me figure out why the anonymous type returned by the query cannot be cast to `UserPoolDto` even though the properties all match?

Thanks

Comment: if you know the type is of `UserPoolDto`, then any specific reason for creating an anonymous type instead of a specific type at the very first moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a compiler encounters a [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) it internally creates a class with a name which is auto generated. As a result even though your anonymous type and `UserPoolDto` dto have same properties they are two different types or classes altogether. So when we try to assign one with another and try to build it eventually results in a cast exception.

There are certain ways to solve the problem in hand by doing a cast as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672742/cast-class-into-another-class-or-convert-class-to-another). However the best approach would be to directly create a dto instance inside of your select.

```
var pools = await _context.Pools
       .Include(p => p.Type)
       .Include(p => p.Type.Category)
       .Include(p => p.Style)
       .Select(p => new UserPoolDto
       {
           Id = p.Id,
           Name = p.Name,
           Key = p.Key,
           TypeName = p.Type.Name,
           CategoryName = p.Type.Category.Name,
           StyleName = p.Style.Name,
           RegCost = p.RegCost,
           RegStartTimeUTC = p.RegStartTimeUTC,
           RegEndTimeUTC = p.RegEndTimeUTC,
           Icon = p.Icon,
           Description = p.Description,
           Instructions = p.Instructions,
           CreatedBy = p.CreatedBy,
       })
       .Where(x => x.CreatedBy == request.UserId)
       .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for me and preserved my types for use with nSwag

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because pool is now an anonymous type not the same type as the pool in your database anymore. Change the  pool in your view model to

```
public class UserPoolVm
{
    public dynamic Pools {get; set;} 
}
```

Then, simply pass the pools to the view model in the method

```
return new UserPoolVm { Pools = pools}; }
```

Pools would resolve the values in the anonymous type at runtime.

Comment: thanks for the answer Qudus, the dynamic type does not work because I have nSwag auto generating typescript interfaces for my front end so I need to have strongly typed classes in my back end.